# Subclass of Android Google Maps API MapView being laggy

Tags: java, android, google-maps, touch, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a making a custom MapView class by extending the MapView class in the google maps API v2 for Android. One of the purposes of the class is that it will be able to be used without necessarily having to be part of an OnCreate function. I am able to connect to google maps and display the map but it will only respond to a touch if I touch the map a second time after the movement (Example having to tap 3 times for it to recognize a double tap)

Here is the starter code for the class (not including the imports at the top):

```
public class MyMapViewTest extends MapView
{   
public MyMapViewTest (Context context)
    {
    super (context);
    this.onCreate(null);        
    MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
    this.getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40,-80),15));
    this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

and here is an example of how I am using it in a fragment:

```
bob = new MyMapViewTest(this.getApplicationContext());
this.addContentView(bob, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Is there something else I am missing in my class that could be causing the lag? I have tried the class in several applications and the lag is always present, it almost seems like it only gets the touch input after being touched a second time.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you debugging? Maps are considerably slower while debugging. Does it behave the same when you are not debugging?

Comment: yes it has the same behavior whether I am debugging or not.

Comment: also upon a further test there is also no difference whether or not I pass a bundle or null into the onCreate function call.